# How to make a "very" custom validation using Ruby and 'paperclip'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

In my RoR3 application I require **custom validations** for the 'paperclip' gem. 
**I have to call those in a precise time during the execution of the code** and only **to validate part of the form fields (not all fields in the form)**.

So I made something in the way explained belowe. However it doesn't work, probably because I not (and I don't know how to) "fill" the uploading file ('paperclip' parameters) to make my custom validation on it.

What i made is:

In the view:

```
<%= form_for(@account, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  ...
    <%= f.label :avatar %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In the controller:

```
...

update
  ...
  @account.validates_account_avatar(params[:account])
  ...
end

...
```

In the model:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100#",
      :small  => "150x150>" }

  def validates_account_avatar(account)
    allowed_mime_types = %w{"image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"} 
    max_size = 2048 

    self.errors.add( :avatar, "must be a file" ) if account[:avatar].blank?
    self.errors.add( :avatar, "isn't a valid image format") if allowed_mime_types.one? {|allowed_content_type| allowed_content_type.match(account[:avatar].content_type.to_s)}
    self.errors.add( :avatar, "is to big") if account[:avatar].size > max_size

    self.validate

    return true if self.errors.empty?
    return false
  end
```

Debugging parameters I get this:

```
... account"=>{"avatar"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20110119-94706-mxpg37>}, "commit"=>" ...
```

Of course, if you have a better way to resolve this issue, don't hesitate to recommend to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do each of those validations with already existing paperclip validations

**validates_attachment_size**

**validates_attachment_content_type**

**validates_attachment_presence**

these are pre-existing validations with Paperclip, read:https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.

Comment: I know! I need a way to use these validations like I describe in the question. I have to call that on a particular time.

Comment: Any particular reason for that ?. If you could explain that in the question. As far as I am concerned what you are doing in that method, is the same thing. Besides, you don't need to return true or false, if you going add error if a certain valdation fails.

Comment: You could just run **@account.valid?** and run those validations, so it won't be such a overhead.

Comment: If any of those validations fail. It wouldn't let you run, @account.update_attributes(params[:account]), would also return false.

Comment: '@account.valid?' is not good for me, because I have to validate only part of the form fields.